# How to show that the set of vectors are a basis for $P_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I show that {$x^2 - x, x - 1, x$} is a basis for the vector space $P_2$? After putting them in matrix form and reducing to row-echelon form, the matrix had rank 2. I'm really confused

Comment: Look at $a(x^2-x)+b(x-1)+cx=ax^2+(b-a+c)x-b$. Chose $a=\alpha$, $b=-\gamma$ and $c=\beta+\alpha+\gamma$. To get $\alpha x^2+\beta x + \gamma$. Hence, you can construct every Polynomial of 2nd degree. This implies that the functions are a basis for $P_2$.

Comment: @MrYouMath  I like your answer the best, linear independence can be waived if we assume that we know $P_2$ has dimension 3.

Comment: Similar older questions: [Basis for the Space of Quadratic Polynomials $P^(2)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951481/basis-for-the-space-of-quadratic-polynomials-p2-homework-help) and [Showing the polynomials are a basis of $P_2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233950/showing-the-polynomials-are-a-basis-of-p-2). You can probably find more questions on this site on the same topic. (General advice - it is often useful to look whether the list of related questions in the side-bar on the right shows some posts that might be useful for you.)

Comment: Since you claim that you have find out that the corresponding matrix has rank 2, perhaps you could show us your computation. If you do this, you have better chance that somebody will be able to give you advice where you have made a mistake. (I have written below my computation. From my post you can also see how to write matrices in the posts on this site.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote in your post that:

> After putting them in matrix form and reducing to row-echelon form, the matrix had rank 2.

Here is the matrix corresponding to the given polynomials. (The matrix is obtained as the coefficients when these polynomials are expressed in using the basis $x^2,x,1$ for the space $P_2$.) And also the computation of rref.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &-1 & 0\\
0 & 1 &-1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &-1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 &-1
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 &-1
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that it suffices to show that this set spans $P_2$, then it follows directly that it is a basis (since $P_2$ has dimension 3). Observe that $$(x^2-x)+x=x^2$$ $$-(x-1)+x=1$$ And we know that {$1,x,x^2$} is a basis for $P_2$. Hence this shows {$x^2 - x, x - 1, x$} is a basis.

Answer (score 2):

Outline :

(1) Show that any polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$ in $P_2$ can be expressed as a linear combination of these.
(2) Show that if $a_1(x^2 - x) + a_2(x-1) + a_3x = 0$, then $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 0$.

This became a little to big for comment and hence posting it as an outline answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: ( I suppose $P^2$ is the space of second degree polynomial on $\mathbb{R}$)

Note that, $\forall a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ we have:
$$
a(x^2-x)-c(x-1)+(a+b+c)x= ax^2 +bx+ c
$$